# Who is responsible of the auto-incrementation of a primary key between MySQL and Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, auto-increment

*MySQL*

```sql
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id_role` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_role`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

*Hibernate*

```java
@Entity
public class Role {

    private Integer idRole;

    @Column(name = "id_role", precision = 10)
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    public Integer getIdRole() {
        return idRole;
    }

    public void setIdRole(Integer idRole) {
        this.idRole = idRole;
    }

}
```

Given the above background, who is responsible of the auto-incrementation of the `id_role` column when creating a new `role`? In other words, does Hibernate set the primary key value before running the `create` SQL statement, or does it set it to `null` and let MySQL auto-increments the field while getting back the chosen primary key?

Comment: I sure hope it would be MySQL, as Hibernate can never know if any key was removed or reused from another client.

Comment: If the table says `auto_increment` then it's MySQL who generates the number. An ORM can't calculate a truly unique integer primary key.

Comment: It depends on what you meany by truly unique ;) . An ORM could calculate a pseudo-unique integer primary key. Its just inefficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use a MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, you are supposed to use an `IDENTITY` strategy:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Which is what you'd get when using `AUTO` with MySQL:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

Which is actually equivalent to

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

Comment: So you mean that IDENTITY and AUTO have the same behavior for a MySQL database?

Comment: Right, So ultimately Hibernate will be using underlying identity mechanism for MySql

Answer (score 3):

If you specify `GenerationType.IDENTITY` , then the database will be in charge assigning the initial identifier. So, using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

would leave the DB in-charge.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely the database. Each db dialect has a slightly different way for Hibernate to then query what that newly assigned ID was so it can set it on your entity